# mysql join based on $get value

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables.

contacts and complaints.

contacts has 3 columns:

```
contact_id, contact_name, score
```

complaints has 4 columns:

```
complaint_id, contact_id, score_deduction, complaint_type
```

I am able to obtain value `$_GET['complaint_id']` from previous page.

What i am trying to do is delete the record with that particular complaint_id and get the value of complaints.score_deduction and add it back to contacts.score.

I have spent hours and cant seem to figure it out.

Please help.

```
if (isset($_GET['complaint_id'])) {
record_set('complaints',"SELECT * FROM add_complaints WHERE complaint_id = ".$_GET['complaint_id']."");
$contact_id = $row_complaints['contact_id'];
record_set('contact',"SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_id = $contact_id");
$score = $row_contact['contact_score'];
echo $score;

}
```

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['complaint_id'])) {
record_set('complaints',"SELECT * FROM add_complaints WHERE complaint_id = ".$_GET['complaint_id']."");
$contact_id = $row_complaints['contact_id'];`
record_set('contact',"SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contact_id = $contact_id");
$score = $row_contact['contact_score'];
echo $score;

}

Comment: Please place in your question so format is legible.

Comment: actual table names are add_complaints and contacts

Comment: Your code appears to be vulnerable to injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just combine that into a single query.

```
SELECT * FROM add_complaints AS ac
INNER JOIN contacts AS c on ac.contact_id = c.contact_id
WHERE ac.complaint_id = ?
```

I am not familiar with whatever you are using to make the DB queries. But I assume you would know how to get the contact id, current score, and score deduction values. And make the update query and delete queries from there.

IF you wanted to get more fancy and just update the contact record in place without needing to select anything you could also do:

```
UPDATE add_complaints AS ac
INNER JOIN contacts AS c on ac.contact_id = c.contact_id
SET c.score = c.score - ac.score_deduction
WHERE ac.complaint_id = ?
```

Then just delete the complaint

```
DELETE FROM add_complaints WHERE complaint_id = ?
```

Comment: Mike, thank you so much for taking the time. I have really been banging my head against the wall. I am pretty new to all of this.

Comment: @smitty - welcome to StackOverflow =) Don't forget to mark answers that resolve your question. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more info.

Comment: lethalMango all marked. I will be hanging out here for quite a long time i think.